# Dynamic ionic 2 tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

im trying to make dynamic tabs from an array in the .ts file.

I got this template as multi-tab component:

```
<ion-content class="myclass">
  <ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top">
    <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" tabTitle="tab.title" [root]="tab.component"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

This is my multitab.ts component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'multi-tab',
  templateUrl: 'multitab.html'
})
export class multiTab {

  tabs : any = [];

  constructor() {
      this.tabs.push({title: 'Snacks',  component: Snacks});
      this.tabs.push({title: 'Drinks',  component: Drinks});
      this.tabs.push({title: 'Frozen',  component: Frozen});
  }
}
```

But my custom component its only showing the first one with all functionality like it was a single tab/list not an ion-tabs.

Im using 2.0.0 rc-2 version of ionic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer, my tabbar its just under the header, thats why its seems like it doesn't appear. I post this if someone has this problem too.

Comment: how you call this "multi-tab" Tab in your page?